# The binary you uploaded was invalid. A pre-release beta version of the SDK was used to build the application

Tags: iphone, binary, app-store-connect

I am having a problem submitting my new app to the appstore. ItunesConnect gives me the error:

The binary you uploaded was invalid. A pre-release beta version of the SDK was used to build the application.

I haven't changed anything, I can compile to a ad-hoc certificate and that works fine. I uploaded another app yesterday and that worked fine too. All the targets and project info is set to compile to the base SDK iPhone OS 3.0. I even upgraded to the latest SDK but same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Was it built with a pre-release beta version? Which version are you using to build?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they've worked out the kinks to compile previous versions of iPhone OS if you have the 3.2 beta SDK installed. Which is to say, 3.2 can't guarantee that it can compile 3.0 exactly like 3.0 did. I think you'll need to use a box that has 3.1.3 installed instead.

Comment: Looked at apple's site at developer.apple.com/iphone in the 3.2 beta section, and it says that 3.2 is for development purposes only. So yes, if you're using 3.2, you'll need to get a different machine or use the 3.1.3 sdk to compile instead. 

If you're not using 3.2, you should file a bug report to apple at http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: And you can't download SDK 3.1.3 any more, at least not from the official site. Talk about catch-22.