# iPhone submission: "The binary you uploaded was invalid. A pre-release beta version of the SDK was used to build the application"

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, xcodebuild

I have Xcode 3.2.3 (Pre-release) and an iPhone with OS 4. I just finished my game using Cocos2d for iPhone OS 3, and I want to put it on the AppStore.

I followed this tutorial [Building Your App for Distribution](http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/build.html), and when I upload my .zip file, I get this error : "The binary you uploaded was invalid. A pre-release beta version of the SDK was used to build the application."

I don't understand why I have this message... here are some screenshots of the configuration of my project :
[alt text http://ple100.free.fr/iph/overview.png](http://ple100.free.fr/iph/overview.png)
[alt text http://ple100.free.fr/iph/info.png](http://ple100.free.fr/iph/info.png)
(if you need other informations, ask me)

And I have also this warning during the compilation that I don't understand :
[alt text http://ple100.free.fr/iph/warning.png](http://ple100.free.fr/iph/warning.png)

An other thing (that is maybe connected): when I launch the iphone simulator 3.2 for my app, it's an iPad that shows up.

If you have any idea who can I upload my app to AppStore... Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467578/itunes-connect-rejects-my-binary-because-i-used-a-pre-release-version-of-the-sdk among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message (“The binary you uploaded was invalid. A pre-release beta version of the SDK was used to build the application”) is telling you **exactly** what is wrong. You can't upload anything to the AppStore with pre-release software.

You'll to reinstall the current SDK and build the application with that.