# App Store submission problem: A pre-release beta version of the SDK was used to build the application

Tags: iphone, xcode, store

I upload my app to app store, I already build my apps using device - 3.1  , which should be the a release version of app store. How can I avoid this warning? thz....

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of these recent questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466399/the-binary-you-uploaded-was-invalid-a-pre-release-beta-version-of-the-sdk-was-us , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467578/itunes-connect-rejects-my-binary-because-i-used-a-pre-release-version-of-the-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've answered your own question. You're using an SDK which is currently in beta, I'm assuming 3.2. Go to the Apple dev center and download the 3.1.3 SDK:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the Beta version of XCode to build, even when you build against an older SDK. You can install the Beta 3.2 and the official 3.1 in two different directories. This question was answered before btw.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xcode and the iPhone SDK are you using? It sounds like you might be using an old (or very new) version of the build tools.